# What happens if readObject() of ObjectInputStream is invoked on empty inputStream?

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization

What would happen if I invoke the readObject function on an ObjectInputStream that doesn't contain data?

Will it throw an I/O exception?

I'm trying to read and write data across threads using PipedInputStream wrapped with ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Does it reach the end of the stream (no possibility of any more data arriving any more, e.g. by tte `PipedOutputStream` on the other side being closed) or is there just no data at the moment (possible for more data being sent)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out, the readObject was blocking the thread till data was added into the stream, but if I close the stream during this blocked state, it would throw an EOFException

When you call readObject() on a DataInputStream, it will block until there is data available to read. If you close the stream while it is blocked, it will throw an EOFException. This is because the DataInputStream will try to read data from the stream, but the stream will be closed and there will be no data to read.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will throw an IOException because it cannot deserialize the object you'rea sking for

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/exceptions.html